# Creating and Printing a Linked List with words from user input

Tags: c, linked-list, user-input, nodes

I am trying to create a linked list which stores words from user input and then prints them.
My code works, however I want to modify it to prompt the user after every word, until the last word which is "end".
Any hints as to how I can do this?
RIght now the code prompts the user and the user can enter words separated by spaces until they press enter, then the linked list is printed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct list *ptr;
typedef struct list {
    char data;
    ptr next;
} node;

void insert(ptr *H, char c);
void freeList(ptr *H);
void printList(ptr H);

int main() {
    ptr H = NULL;
    int c;

    printf("enter a single word:\n");

    while (((c = getchar()) != EOF) && c != '\n')
        insert(&H, (char) c);

    printList(H); /*print the list*/
    freeList(&H); /*free the list*/
    printf("\n");
    prinf("Please enter a single word:\n");

    return 0;
}

void insert(ptr *H, char c) {
    while (*H)
        H = &(*H)->next;

    *H = malloc(sizeof(**H));
    (*H)->data = c;
    (*H)->next = NULL;
}

void freeList(ptr *H) {

    while (*H) {
        ptr tmp = *H;
        *H = (*H)->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}

void printList(ptr H) {
    // NOTE: No need for a pointer-to-pointer here.
    while (H) {
        printf("%c", H->data);
        H = H->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what's stopping you? If you wrote that code, it would appear you know enough to make that change. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am not sure how to check if a word is (end) and finish the loop. I could use strcmp() but I am getting chars not a string.

Comment: You should use line oriented input instead of character oriented input.

Comment: Write something that takes a string, and the start of a linked list. Walk down the list, comparing the character in the code to the next character in the string. Or write something that walks down a list, and assembles the string it represents

Comment: @b4hand, I'll bet this is an assignment so probably can't use line-oriented.

Answer (score 0):

sample of modified

```
int isEndKeyword(ptr H){
    const char *end_keyword = "end";

    while(*end_keyword){
        if(H){
            if(*end_keyword++ != H->data)
                return 0;//false
        } else //short
            return 0;
        H = H->next;
    }
    return H == NULL;//match
}

int main() {
    ptr H = NULL;
    int c;
    char prev = ' ';

    while(1){
        c = getchar();
        if(isspace(c) || c == EOF){
            if(!isspace(prev)){ //word is exist
                if(!isEndKeyword(H)){
                    printList(H); /* print the word */
                    printf("\n");
                } else {
                    c = EOF;
                }
                freeList(&H); /* free the word */
            }
            if(c == EOF)
                break;//loop end
        } else {
            insert(&H, (char) c);
        }
        prev = c;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How would I go about if I want to prompt the user with a printer statement saying "enter next word" after EACH word? Thankyou

Comment: @babichild Since the newline is a separator of the input from the user, it would be nice if a prompt after detecting a newline(`'\n'`).